# Mayavi network animation with plot3d and points3d

Tags: networkx, mayavi

I try to animate a number of nodes with mayavi. Now I want to include links between the nodes depending on their proximity and illustrate this in the animation as well, but it doesn't work. If I use x_pos instead of x_neigh I will see some links between the nodes, however I want to control what links to show. Anyone can help?

```
plt = mlab.points3d(x_pos, y_pos, z_pos, resolution=5, scale_factor=8)
plt2 = mlab.plot3d(x_neigh, y_neigh, z_neigh, tube_radius=None)
msplt = plt.mlab_source
msplt2 = plt2.mlab_source
@mlab.animate(delay=100,ui=False)
def anim():
    while True:
        # Build nodes list
        x_pos = np.array([(swarm[i].x_pos) for i in range(SIZE)])
        y_pos = np.array([(swarm[i].y_pos) for i in range(SIZE)])
        z_pos = np.array([(swarm[i].z_pos) for i in range(SIZE)]) 
        # Build links list
        x_neigh, y_neigh, z_neigh =    create_geometric_random_graph(x_pos,y_pos,z_pos)
        msplt.set(x=x_pos, y=y_pos, z=z_pos)
        msplt2.set(x=x_neigh, y=y_neigh, z=z_neigh)
        yield
anim()
mlab.show()
```

Comment: I tried "reset" instead of "set" for msplt2 because the number of links varies in each run, but don't have any success :-(

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to toggle individual links of a `plot3d` graph. One option would be to call `plot3d` in the loop. Another (more involved, not straightforward) option would be to attach visibility scalars to every edge, and use an opacity transfer function to toggle visibility of individual edges. For the latter approach, see e.g. https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/blob/master/tvtk/util/ctf.py to get started